# How can I get multiple data?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I can show just one customer, I know the problem is because I use `FirstOrDefault` in my LINQ.

How can get another customer? I still don't understand the concept of `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`.

```
public int getNota(DateTime dt, int lap)
{
    DataClassesPelleDataContext myDb = new DataClassesPelleDataContext();
    var nota = (from u in myDb.TBL_TRANSAKSI_SEWA_LAPANGAN_REGULERs
                where u.TGL_PEMAKAIAN.Value.Date == dt.Date && u.ID_LAPANGAN == lap
                select u.ID_SEWA).FirstOrDefault();
    return nota;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know for sure what you are trying to achive
But you can use

```
var notasIds = yDb.TBL_TRANSAKSI_SEWA_LAPANGAN_REGULERs
              .Where(u => u.TGL_PEMAKAIAN.Value.Date == dt.Date && u.ID_LAPANGAN == lap)
              .Select(n => n.ID_SEWA)
              .ToList();
```

and then loop over the notas with

```
foreach (var sewaId in notasIds)
{
    // to logic here
}
```

You can also comment .Select() call and get whole objects.

Regars

Comment: I wish, I can show an image to you, so you can understand what I want.

Comment: If you wish, you can post image to some image provider, like imgur.com and then paste the link

Comment: You want to create an expression that will return green highlighted rows?

Comment: no,, I only can show one customer , actually in that that date, I have more than one customer base on date and time. what I try  to do is I want to get another customer, so in my linq can check sequence, and get next customer . green highlighted rows is just a status for a customer. hope you understand